# Move inactive rows to another table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a table where when a row is created, it will be active for 24 hours with some writes and lots of reads. Then it becomes inactive after 24 hours and will have no more writes and only some reads, if any.

Is it better to keep these rows in the table or move them when they become inactive (or via batch jobs) to a separate table?  Thinking in terms of performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends largely on how big your table will get, but if it grows forever, and has a significant number of rows per day, then there is a good chance that moving old data to another table would be a good idea.  There are a few different ways you could accomplish this, and which is best depends on your application and data access patterns.

1. Essentially as you said, when a row becomes "old", INSERT to the archive table, and DELETE from the current table.
2. Create a new table every day (or perhaps every week, or every month, depending on how big your dataset is), and never worry about moving old rows.  You'll just have to query old tables when accessing old data, but for the current day, you only ever access the current table.
3. Have a "today" table and a "all time" table.  Duplicate the "today" rows in both tables, keeping them in sync with triggers or other mechanisms.  When a row becomes old, simply delete from the "today" table, leaving the "all time" row in tact.

One advantage to #2, that may not be immediately obvious, is that I believe MySQL indexes can be optimized for read-only tables. So by having old tables that are *never* written to, you can take advantage of this extra optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Generally moving rows between tables in proper RDBMS should not be necessary.

I'm not familiar with mysql specifics, but you should do fine with the following:

- Make sure your timestamp column is indexed
- In addition, you can use `active BOOLEAN default true` column

  - Make a batch run every day to mark >24h old rows inactive
  - Use a partial index for timestamp column so only rows marked active are indexed
  - Remember to have timestamp and active = TRUE in your where conditions to hit indexes. Use EXPLAIN a lot.

Answer (score 1):

That all depends on the balance between ease of programming, and performance.  Performance wise, yes it will definitely be faster.  But whether the speed increase is worth the effort is hard to say.

I've worked on systems that run perfectly fine with millions of rows.  However, if the data is ever growing it does eventually become a problem.

I've worked on a database storing transaction logging for automated equipment.  It generates hundreds of thousands of events per day.  After a year, the queries just wouldn't run at acceptable speeds any more.  We now keep the last month's worth of logs in the main table (millions of rows still), and move older data to archive tables.

None of the application's functionality ever looks in the archive table (if you do a query of the transaction log, it will return no results).  It is only really kept for emergency use, and is just queried with any standalone database query tool.  Because the archive has well over a hundred million rows, and the nature of this emergency use is generally unplannable (and therefore mostly un-indexed) queries, they can take a long time to run.

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution. To have another table containing only the active records (tblactiverecords). When the number of active records is really small, you could just do an inner join and get the active records. This should take very less time because primary key by default are indexed in mysql. As your rows become inactive, you could delete them from the tblactiverecords table.

```
create table tblrecords (id int primary key, data text);
```

Then,

```
create table tblactiverecords (tblrecords_id primary key);
```

you can do

```
select data from tblrecords join tblactiverecords on tblrecords.id = tblactiverecords.tblrecords_id;
```

to get all data that are active.